# Unique duplicate rows with range

Tags: python

I have a file like so:

```
x 48012  F 1.000
x 48169  R 0.361
x 87041  R 0.118
x 9032   R 0.176
x 9150   R 0.521
```

I wanted to filter out rows having in the result file a unique value based on whether column 1,2 and 3 are the same - with a tolerance of +/- 200 for column2.
So for example the first two rows

```
x 48012  F 1.000
x 48169  R 0.361
```

would become

```
x 48012  F 1.000
```

because 48169-48012 is 157 and that is in the ±200 range

Overall, the end file would be

```
    x 48012  F 1.000
    x 87041  R 0.118
    x 9032   R 0.176
```

I've tried

```
out=open('result.txt', 'w')
my_file= open('test.txt', 'r')
seen = set()
for line in my_file:
        line=line.strip().split('\t')
        if line[0]==seen[0] and line[2]==seen[2] and ((int(line[1])==int(seen[1]-200)) or (int(line[1])==(seen[1]-200))):
            out.write(line)
```

but sets can't be indexed

Comment: Your question is very confusing 1) *Unique duplicate rows*? 2) *last first two rows*?. Please try to better explain what you want. Are you wanting to delete those duplicate rows, flag them, or what?

Comment: did my edit to the question help?

Comment: not much. I had rephrased it but your edit overwrote mine. "unique" is not a verb in English - so things get downhill from there.

Comment: So... For row in matrix, if row[row_value 2] (1 if zero-indexed) minus row+1[row_value 2] is smaller or bigger than 200, delete row+1 (entire next row)? Is that it?

Comment: Yes that is what I'd like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use Set here because you have to break the elements into tokens so they are awkward to manage. I would use a pair of two-dimensional arrays, one for your candidate lines and one for results.

I would read the whole file into a candidates array and create an empty results array. Then I would traverse the candidates array and look for matches in the results array. If I didn't find a match in the results array I would copy the candidate into the results array.

Something like:

```
candidates = []
results = []
for line in my_file:
    candidates.append(line.split('\t'))
for line in candidates:
    seen = false
    for possible_match in results:
        if matching_line(possible_match, line):
            seen = true
    if seen:
        continue
    else:
        results.append(line)
```

Then you need a function to decide if two arrays match:

```
function matching_line(array1, array2):
    if array1[0] = array2[0]
    ..etc
```

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense and it seems like this is a way to get all duplicated lines in the file, though for the function part do I return array1?

Comment: No, you should just return a boolean which is true if the two lines need to be merged and false if they don't.

Comment: and how is 'seen' being used?

Comment: 'seen' means that a match already exists in the results array. If seen is true, we don't want to add this entry to the array because we already have an entry that is too similar.

Comment: okay, have done this, having trouble with the format of the ouput in the end, even when I convert it to a string. Each line has quotes and square brackets around it

Comment: Can you paste the line of your code that adds the line to the array, the code that prints the array and a sample line of the output please?

Comment: results.append(line)
out.write(str(results))                                                                                              [['x', '48012', 'F', ''1.00\n'],

Comment: At a guess I would say you should write the file like this:

    `for line in results:`

        `for element in line:`

            `out.write(element)`

Comment: I don't know how to format the comment with the correct indentation, you'll have to add that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('result.txt', 'w') as out:
    with open('file_36086075.txt', 'r') as my_file:
        row1 = None
        row2 = None
        for line in my_file:
            if not row1:
                row1=line.strip().split('\t')
            else:
                if not row2:
                    row2=line.strip().split('\t')
            if row1 and row2:
                diff = int(row1[1]) - int(row2[1])
                if row1[0]==row2[0] and row1[2]==row2[2] and (diff >= -200 and diff <= 200):
                    out.write('\t'.join(row1) + '\n')
                    row1 = None
                    row2 = None
                else:
                    out.write('\t'.join(row1) + '\n')
                    row1 = row2
                    row2 = None
```

Comment: it works! but can I ask where seen[] comes into it, is it necessary?

Comment: No, I forgot to delete the line.

Comment: is there a way to iterate this? by putting a while loop infront of for line in my file?